# Is there an iOS GUI skin/theme for Android?

Tags: launcher, themes

Is there an iOS-like skin for Android and/or a launcher with an iOS theme?

Comment: Dev questions are offtopic.  Please see the FAQ.

Comment: Just edit out the dev-part if it's not allowed? The first question still remains unanswered.

Comment: You can edit your own question, but I have done so and voted to reopen.

Comment: will ROM be OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Espier Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.espier.launcher) is a homescreen replacement that mimics iOS quite well, and still allows for some of Android's features to shine through (Widgets, customization, etc).

Unfortunately, it's apparently built by a small Chinese dev shop, so it does have a few quirks. For one, it intalls some bloatware app store that's all in Chinese, although it's easy enough to hide it from the launcher. There's also some weird mis-translations in the app's settings. Despite these shortcomings, it's a faithful reproduction of iOS's homescreen, and the folder/scrolling/long press animations are spot-on.

Answer (score 1):

There's [MIUI](http://en.miui.com/):

> MIUI is one of the most popular Android ROMs in the world. It is based on Android 2.3 and 4.0, featuring better experience and richer themes. MIUI is updated every Friday based on the feedback from its users.

**Regarding the themes:**

- Over 500 themes created by fans available
- Original third-party theme-changing program
- Massive online themes for your choice

Themes can be found at [miuithemes](http://www.miuithemes.com/)

---

**For your specific request**, concerning an iOS-like theme if you can't find it at the provided link, you can find it here:

- xda-developers Thread: [Theme for MIUI to mimic iOS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=792588)
- droidforums Thread: [[Theme] iOS Theme Port](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/team-d1-miui/88899-theme-ios-theme-port.html) (based on the previous)